# Google elevation api

Tags: android, gps, elevation, google-elevation-api

I am developing an android application that log GPS data when I use my bike. GPS altitude informations are not very good so I would like to use google elevation api. 
In detail:
- I log GPS data and at the end I invoke google web service in order to retrieve elevation info for alla GPS coordination saved. 
- in a view I show a map where I like to paint the route, in a second one I paint a chart with elevation data retrived 
- elevation data retrived are stored in applicarion DB

I have two questions: 
1- is the application designed compliant with google policies? 
2- I read about usage limit: if I decide to pubblish the application, every istance of application has private usage counter or all istance concur to a single global counter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well am not clear regarding your question 1. About your second question I think all the request are considered for a global counter. I say so because when you see the quotas in API console there is an option to set usage limit for each user if each user had 25000 request per day then there is no need to set an option like that. Also an app is registered with an API all the users access the same API not different API for each app. So I believe the counter is global.